# how to view ICMP request on public IP

Tags: python, networking, scapy, packet, icmp

I'm trying to check if a "ICMP" request on my public IP is being sent. I'm sending a request from "scapy" in python but i am spoofing the "src" address as my public IP. how do I check incoming "ICMP" requests on my public "IP" or are there any services I can use?

Answer (score -1):

-Use DMZ in config router at your IP local
-Check firewalls rules if block this, in router and in your pc
-Redirrect port in router firewall if not possible use DMZ